# $R$ is semiperfect and $e^2=e\in R$ $\Longrightarrow$ $eRe$ and any factor-ring of $R$ is semiperfect

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, direct-sum, idempotents

Let $R$ be a semiperfect ring and $e^2=e\in R$ an idempotent. Prove that $eRe$ and any factor-ring of $R$ is semiperfect too.

I know that $R$ is a semiperfect ring iff $R$ decomposes to a direct sum of right $R$-modules and each of them has got only one maximal submodule. I don't think it's a useful knowledge.

I also know Muller's theorem: it says that $R$ is semiperfect iff $1$ decomposes to a sum of local orthogonal idempotents. This theorem must be the key but I don't understand exactly how to apply it.

Let $1=e_1+\dots+e_n$ be a decomposition in $R$. Then $[1]=[e_1]+\dots+[e_n]$ is a needed decomposition in a factor-ring. But what about $eRe$? Can one show $e=ee_1e+\dots+ee_ne$ is a desired one? How to prove that $\{ee_ie\}_i$ is a family of ortogonal idempotents?

Can you please help me?

Comment: It's not immediately true that even $\sum[e_i]$ is the decomposition: you'll have to delete the ones for which $[e_i]=[0]$.  But then you should be OK. Secondly, although it is very reasonable to guess,  I can't see how to prove $ee_ie$ is even idempotent.  The problem that $r\mapsto ere$ is not multiplicative is a big issue here.

Comment: @rschwieb, thank you! What if say that, according to the first theorem, $R=\oplus_{i\in I}M_i$ is a decomposition to a direct sum of indecomposable modules such that each of them has got only one maximal submodule, and $eRe=\oplus_{i\in I}eM_ie$ is a corresponding decomposition for $eRe$? Is it possible to prove that $eM_ie$ has got the only maximal submodule? I.e. if $L<N<M_i$ then $eLe<eNe<eM_ie$? Does the strictness of inclusions preserve? Cause if yes we win.

Comment: I wish I knew the answer. It seems like something someone should have done by now. I'm just not sure how the corner ring's modules compare with its original ring.

Comment: Answered in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/395481/are-corner-rings-of-semiperfect-rings-semiperfect/395485#395485

Comment: @MaximNikitin Hope you don't mind: I was interested in the perfect case too.